# How to buy tickets for Stockholm metro?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, stockholm

1. Is whole Stockholm subway in one zone (A zone)?
2. How much does cost one ride for Stockholm metro?
3. Where I can buy tickets?

Comment: The zone system has been deprecated! Look at this question for up-to-date answers: [Can I buy SL Access card with Credit Card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/143742/18374)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, there are multiple zones, mostly you have to cross from one zone to another, hence pay more. Here's the metro zone map:

[image: Stockholm Metro]

2. They sell [16-ticket slips for 200 SEK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_transport_in_Stockholm#SL.27s_zone_system), you need two units (tickets) if you're traveling within a single zone, three units when in two zones (e.g. from A to B) and four if you're traveling between three zones.
3. The easiest way would be getting the tickets at stations, there are vending machines and also sometimes cashiers selling those tickets.

Comment: In fact the enitre subway system is in zone 1. The subways are the red, green and blue lines on the map, with numbers starting with T (from Tunnelbana). The grey and black lines are suburban railway lines. And in part two of your answer I would suggest using the word "units" instead of "tickets" as the latter suggests you need to have three pieces of paper.

Comment: I think it's clearer to think of it as if you're buying 16 separate tickets, but spend a few tickets for each ride. Still, I made the change you suggested and put the word _ticket_ into parenthesis, maybe it's clearer this way.

Comment: Is it allowed to buy one 72 hours travel card for multiple people?

Comment: On the page that @notautogenerated posted, under Visitor Tickets -> Travelcards it says that a 72-hour travel card costs 230 sek, and a travel card can be used only by one person at a time.

Comment: Note that the automated vending machines for single tickets accept credit cards but **no cash** (at least at the station where I tried). Be careful if you plan to travel at a time when human-operated shops are closed.

Comment: One confusion to watch out for: the machines offer an option described as “RED”.  This is not anything to do with the red subway line, as I have known some visitors to assume — it is short for “reducerad”, i.e. reduced fare for the elderly and similar.

Comment: The zone system has been deprecated - there's just one "zone" now in Stockholm.

Answer (score 6):

All of the subway stations are within zone A, but some buses and trains reach outer zones.

A single ride is 45 SEK, but if you have a prepaid travel card (costs 20 SEK) it goes down to 32 SEK. Paper coupon strips are no longer accepted.

You can buy a card at the Central station SL center among other places, and fill it with cash or tickets at the vending machines in every station. Check http://sl.se/en/fares--tickets/ for details.

Comment: wow, this is really expensive...

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to get a SL access card from any Pressbyran store. There is a small admin fee, but it means you can just touch the card at the ticket barriers for the Tunnelbana. **With a SL access card**, the single fare for a journey on the **Tunnelbana** is (in January 2019) 32 krona. You can also use the SL access card on the Pendeltag (commuter rail), trams, commuter ferries in the city centre (but **not** Waxholmsbolaget ferries, *unless* you have certain types of pre-loaded travelcard), and buses.

Using the SL access card, you can also combine modes of transport under one single fare, provided that the last leg of the journey is commenced within 75 minutes of the first leg of the journey having been commenced. You can see what that single fare would be from the journey planner at (in English): https://sl.se/en/

Comment: Can you please include the cost of the card and the cost of a ride without the card if they still sell those? Then people can compare whether it is worth buying the card.