# Can I buy SL Access card with Credit Card?

Tags: payment-cards, sweden

As [sweden is 'cashless'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109513/swedish-cashless-economy-for-tourism), I am wondering if I can avoid currency exchanges altogether by purchasing (and topping up) the SL access card with my credit card. Is it possible? Or should I fetch some cash to get the cards?

Comment: Any particular reason why you suspect you wouldn't be able to? Is it an American card that doesn't have a PIN?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Many similar stored-value cards around the world do not allow top-up with credit card

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can now use your contactless card to travel in Stockholm without a travel card or mobile phone. Simply tap the contactless card against the green readers with glass, not the blue ones.

---

All places that sell SL Access Cards accept credit/debit cards. Almost all accept cash.

You **can't** buy tickets on busses or on trains. *SL has [a help page](https://sl.se/en/eng-info/fares/buying-tickets/) about buying tickets.*

You can use [**Mobile Phone Tickets**](https://sl.se/en/eng-info/fares/app/) everywhere in Stockholm. Just download the [official SL app](https://sl.se/en/eng-info/fares/app/) for your phone. It accepts credit/debit cards and some Swedish payment methods.

---

## Ways of getting phyical tickets

You will find **self-service machines** at all larger stations and select smaller ones, they only accept credit/debit cards.

[image: SL Self-Service Machines]

All the **entrances to train & metro stations** are manned and you can buy tickets and access cards there.

[image: Manned entrance to train station]

Many **kiosks, or "tobacco shops"** as they usually call themselves, sell SL Tickets and Access Cards *without markup*. Look for an SL Flag or some other mentioning of "SL Tickets".

[image: Kiosk with the SL Flag]

There are also a few [**SL Center**'s](https://sl.se/en/eng-info/contact/visit-cutomer-services/) in Stockholm. There are 2 in Stockholm Central but there are also many Pressbyrån there that also sell the tickets. At SL Center they can answer any question that you might have about the public transportation system as well as sell you tickets.

[image: SL Center at Stockholm Central main hall]

---

### Where to find these places

Go to [SL.se/en](https://sl.se/en/) and use the map. Choose **Sales points** and find nearby place.

[image: SL.se/en map with arrow pointing at "Sale Points".]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I bought an SL Access card+travelcard from a manned metro gate with a credit card in February 2019. In May 2018 I bought one with value from the SL Center with a credit card.

There is also plenty of retailers that sells SL Access cards and offer topups, probably all of them accept credit cards, at least Pressbyrån does. Check the map here: https://sl.se/en/
Use the icon on the top right and tick sales points instead of stations. Green icons shows where you can buy and top up SL Access.

Visa and Mastercard are the universally accepted cards in Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to buy the SL access card and the 7-days pass with the credit card. They asked me for the passport (well, ID), for reason I dunno.(Maybe they needed to check my age?)

Comment: There are no age requirements - maybe you didn't use PIN with your credit card? Then Swede's must check name and signature on the card against an ID.

Comment: That's probably the case, all the terminals in Sweden didn't ask me for the PINs.

Comment: We only use chip and pin in Sweden - and signature if we forget our pins.

Comment: Signatures don't work in Sweden anymore after EU's new payment directives.